# How to detect and resolve huge string usage issue

Tags: c#, memory

When use WinDbg to trace memory usage issue, I found there are million strings which occupy 100+MBs totally. Our application is a financial type APP, so there are ten thousands accounts and each account has many string type properties.

My question is: is there any good articles/resource about tuning memory issue, especial for the string type? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to look at your design.Having Millions of strings is probably not a good idea/design.

Although not sure what exactly your design is,you can tune your strings using

- StringBuilder
- String interning

With a normal string object ,every modification on the string creates a new string object and this can bring unnecessary memory pressure.You can alleviate this problem using the stringbuilder class.The StringBuilder object maintains a internal character array and any modifications doesnt create a new string object,rather the internal character array is modified.The string is obtained by calling the ToString() on the StringBuilder object.

More here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx

String interning is a process where you place unique strings on a common pool and is shared across applications.This reduces the need to create a string if it is already created and interned in the pool.

More here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a question about the string intern. If I even don't know which string is used frequently and duplicate, how can i use this tec to improve the memory usage?

Answer (score 0):

`StringBuilder` might be the way to go. You need to split the string. You need large memory and `StringBuilder` You have to do this directly I think.

Comment: I know StringBuilder. I don't think it is a problem here, since directly operate string only effect the performance (more temp garbage), but never cause memory leak, doesn't it?

Comment: Look at the memory usage. Use extensive debugging. It is probably your design. Is there a lot of references everywhere in the code. Are there static class variables, links and references to objects everywhere. The garbage collector will collect unreferenced and unused strings/objects that is not being used. It is your application design I think. I think it is designed to cache strings or the design is at fault.